# Max execution time out session start

Tags: php, session, timeout, session-cookies, session-timeout

I am getting a `Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in D:\wamp\www\session_start.php on line 2`

I am putting this file above all my scripts. And those randomly getting the error. Can anyone tell what is happening ? And how can fix this ?

```
<?php
session_start(); //this line gets the error
  if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    if (isset($_COOKIE['user_id']) && isset($_COOKIE['username'])) {
      $_SESSION['user_id'] = $_COOKIE['user_id'];
      $_SESSION['username'] = $_COOKIE['username'];
    }
  }

  ?>
```

Comment: See if this answer helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/2999737/2623477. It did for me

Comment: @dailysleaze d you think it will be stuck after a year ? shit just say been 2 years damn time flies