# Fatal error on session_start()

Tags: php

I have this function to track a user session time.

```
function sessionTracker(){
    ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 86400);
    ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 86400);
    $sid = session_id();
    if ($sid != '') {
        //echo "Session exists!";
    } else {
        //echo "No current session exists! Starting...";
        session_start();
    }

    if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
    {
        header("location:login.php");
        exit();
    }
```

But I'm getting a "Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded" when it hits the session_start(); line. Is there a better function or how do i fix this? I don't get it all the time, but its always that line.

```
function sessionReup() {
    $time = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];

    //for a 30 minute timeout, specified in seconds
    $timeout_duration = 1800;

    /*
      Here we look for the user’s LAST_ACTIVITY timestamp. If
      it’s set and indicates our $timeout_duration has passed,
      blow away any previous $_SESSION data and start a new one.
    */
    if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && ($time -     $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) > $timeout_duration) {
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        session_start();
        header("location:login.php");
        exit();
    }

    /*
     Finally, update LAST_ACTIVITY so that our timeout
     is based on it and not the user’s login time.
    */
    $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = $time;
}
```

Comment: try to increase max_execution_time in php.ini

Comment: But if increase the time, doesn't that increase the time the page would load? So the user would wait even longer?

Comment: yes but if the page needs loading time then we should give it. not all the pages take long execution time

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2999737/2082464

Comment: I guess. Can I just do ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); to see if that works first? And how much time should I set?

Comment: Adrien, I read that a couple days ago and thats when I added the if statement. I thought it was trying to create a session when one already existed and that why it was timing out.

Comment: @Meenesh If the site takes more than 30 seconds to load then something is seriously wrong. You don't fix it by waiting more.

Comment: Have you tried using [session_write_close()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php)? 
@deceze It appears that session_start() is a blocking function, that's why the max execution time exceeds. But indeed increasing the execution time is definitely not a solution.

Comment: deceze, right. Thats what i was thinking. I'd rather fix the error than put a band aid on it.

Comment: Adrien, I did not because what I understand that will destroy my session. Does it make sense to destroy and recreate a session everytime they hit a certain page just to track a session for timeout?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to achieve, and only seeing part of the code doesn't help. The cause of the timeout occurring is almost certainly due to the blocking nature of sessions - you're trying to start a session that is already open.

Comment: Eborbob, that is the full function. Do you want to see my whole page of functions? Yes I understand the blocking, but why wouldn't the if statement catch that?

Comment: @moe The `if` statement isn't checking whether the requested session is open - it's checking if a session is open *in this process*. The requested session could still be open in another process, e.g. if using AJAX requests. I'm still not entirely sure how this code is used to `track a user session time` - if I knew what you were hoping to achieve I'm sure a better solution could be proposed my someone here.

Comment: Eborbob, I'll post the other function I have that goes with this one. Basically what I am trying to achieve is a logout after a certain time of inactivity. This function is called on each page to keep track of session time and session variables. The other function which is called only when they go to a certain page, and it will renew the session time.

Comment: Try using a session handler working on memcached or redis and when you write your session give it a ttl, you can update ttl whenever you want. If user don't do anything, session will expire within your given ttl.

Answer (score 0):

The code does not show a line, which could be responsible for a long runtime.
Sessions are stored to hard disk. Is the device really really slow?
Did you exchanged the session handler?

But you can reduce your code to:

```
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    header("location:login.php");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: This is my original code.  `ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 86400);
    ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 86400);
    session_start();
    
    if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
    {
        header("location:login.php");
        exit();
    }`

Comment: The device is literally 2 weeks old. its a brand new IBM AS/400.

Comment: are you doing more than one request at time? are you using ajax? maybe you are running in a session lock problem. the sessions files are locked exlusive by a request.the next request for the same session will wait until timeout or until i gets the sessions file access.

Comment: At the time I get this error I am not. I'm running a pho function to update a table and then header redirect

Comment: You could try to install xdebug and record a profile to see which function takes so long.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found out what the problem was. On the ajax calls I was calling php pages that had old code because it was old code and I never updated this pages. The culprit,

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}
```